# Tabela com Chave Composta sem repetição

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, chave-composta

**Como faço uma tabela com chave composta, mas que eu não possa repetir a combinação de valores.**

Eu to querendo armazenar **AMIZADES**, usando uma sintaxe semelhante a está:

`tb_amizades
id_usuario_um
id_usuario_dois`

```
SELECT * FROM tb_amizades 
WHERE id_usuario_um = id OR id_usuario_dois = id 
LIMIT (qtd_de_amigos);
```

Esse SELECT está inconsistente, mas da pra dar a ideia do que to querendo faz. To usando o LIMIT para caso eu tenha 5 amigos e o banco possuir mais de 100 registros e o sistema não ter que buscar em todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste caso específico, é possível criar uma *primary key* composta.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_amizades 
(
    id_usuario_um INT NOT NULL,
    id_usuario_dois INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tb_amizades_id_usu_um_id_usu_dois_pk 
      PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario_um, id_usuario_dois)
);
```

Pra todos os outros casos, é possível criar um índice composto

```
CREATE TABLE tb_amizades 
(
    id_usuario_um INT NOT NULL,
    id_usuario_dois INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tb_amizades_id_usu_um_id_usu_dois_uindex 
    ON tb_amizades (id_usuario_um, id_usuario_dois);
```